# Does Heat Equation really describe thermodynamic temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, equilibrium, non-equilibrium

We learnt that in the first PDE course, temperature profile could be described by heat equation.
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial t} \;=\; \alpha \nabla^{2}u \tag{1} \label{heat-eqn}
\end{align}
where $u(\mathbf{r}, t)$ is temperature at position $\mathbf{r}$ and at time $t$.

In thermodynamics (equilibrium), every process has to be **quasi-static**, and hence we can define temperature $T$. But Eq. (\ref{heat-eqn}) is time dependent, and probably not quasi-static, and non-equilibrium. So how can the above PDE describes thermodynamic temperature ?

That also leads to another question. In equilibrium thermodynamics, we always assume the process is quasi-static. But in reality it is not the case, so how can we measure the **deviation** from this quasi-static assumption?

Comment: "So how can the above PDE describes thermodynamic temperature ?": What makes you think equation 1 (the Fourier Heat Equation) describes "thermodynamic temperature">

Comment: I am not sure. I was taught in PDE course it is temperature long time ago. Now I have doubt on it

Comment: @BobD What makes you think equation 1 (the Heat Diffusion Equation, derived from Fourier's Equation) does not describe thermodynamic temperature?

Comment: @K_inverse If temperature represents the average microscopic kinetic energy, then why shouldn't it be defined for any time, regardless of whether the system is at equilibrium or in a transient state? What's the source of the idea that temperature can only be defined at equilibrium?